# SwiftUI transparent TabView (without background blur)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitabbar, tabview

From what I found on the internet, the Tabview in this version of Swift is meant to be transparent.

But in my case it always dispalys a grayish tone with a line on top when there is something underneath it in the view it is displaying. If I scroll down to a space in that view which is empty, the tabview becomes transparent again.

**I have been trying to find a solution to this for ages but I'm a absolute noob. Can someone please help me fix this and make it always transparent? Thank you so much!**

Screenshots:

[Grayish when there's something underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwO8p.png)

[Transparent when there's nothing underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG6V0.png)

Comment: Should have been clearer about what are you trying to achieve, and what is that you already have, but seemingly `configureWithTransparentBackground()` can help you out (see updated answer).

Comment: @GeriBorbás This does indeed solve the problem and change the navigation bar to transparent. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UIBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarappearance/3197999-configurewithtransparentbackgrou).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        let transparentAppearence = UITabBarAppearance()
        transparentAppearence.configureWithTransparentBackground() //    
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = transparentAppearence
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            List {
                ForEach(1...40, id: \.self) { eachRowIndex in
                    Text("Row \(eachRowIndex)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]